# Upgrading to Spring Boot 1.5.1, @Valid no longer triggering validation

Tags: spring, validation, spring-boot

Upgraded an application to Spring Boot 1.5.1. I have controllers defined like:

```
public ResponseEntity<MappingJacksonValue> save(@Valid @RequestBody Brand brand, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    ...
}
```

When I execute my integration tests and expect validation to fail on `Brand` because of a `@Size` or `@NotNull` constraint, they never fail.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to version 1.5.2.RELEASE and the @valid annotation returned to work.